# Excalidraw react component with Collaboration feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created an component in a react app with a drawing canvas with excalidraw
I did the following steps to implement excalidraw.

1.npm i @excalidraw/excalidraw

2.Created a component named excalidrawComponent.js with following code

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function Excalidraw(props) {
    const [Comp, setComp] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        import("@excalidraw/excalidraw").then((comp) => setComp(comp.Excalidraw));
    }, []);

    return <>
    <div className="excalidraw-component">
     {Comp && <Comp />}
    </div>
    </>
}
```

But I am not able to find the collaborate functionality what we can see in excalidraw statdalone project.
You can find below images to check diffrences.

[[standalone excalidraw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDjSt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGtLT.png)

[[My react application with excalidraw darwing tool]https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVHEq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVHEq.png)

I need a live collaboration button on top and its feature.
How to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.